# The scrollExtend plugin add additional div

Tags: jquery, scroll

I need help with **scrollExtends.js** plugin. I can add content from a database dynamically, but the plugin adds additional `div` to wrap my content. As a result I get `div`s I do not need.

Here is my Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(
    function() {
        var index = +$('.list_item').size()-1;
        var url = 'more.php?index='+index;
    $('.scroll_container').scrollExtend(
    {
        'target': 'div#scroll_items',
        'loadingIndicatorEnabled':true,
        'loadingIndicatorClass':'scrollExtend-loading',
        'url' : function(container) {
            return url;
        }, 
        'onSuccess':function(){
            index += 5;
            url = 'more.php?index='+index;
        }

    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had to hack the plugin in order to achieve the same result you ask for. Simply replace

```
jQuery(new_elem).appendTo(target);
```

in the scrollExtend.js file with:

```
jQuery(new_elem.html()).appendTo(target);
```

this way you'll bypass the extra "div" addition to your DOM

I hope I'm not (too) late! ;)